# in ssis how do I include a reference to a global variable from a script component?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a script component which I need to reference a global variable? I guess I can dtsconfig file. How do I set this and read it back out from my script component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
Me.Variables.YourVariableName
```

this will work only in script component of Data Flow task. In script task you can use like this:

```
Dts.Variables("YourVariableName").Value.ToString
```

All you need is to configure the package variable in the dts config file by specifying the value.

Answer (score 1):

From http://blogs.conchango.com/jamiethomson/archive/2005/02/09/964.aspx :

```
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime
Public Class ScriptMain
  Public Sub Main()
    Dim vars As Variables
    Dts.VariableDispenser.LockOneForWrite("vMyVar", vars)
    vars(0).Value = "Hello World"
    vars.Unlock()
    Dts.TaskResult = Dts.Results.Success
  End Sub
End Class
```

Some more discussion:

http://www.developerdotstar.com/community/node/313

http://www.developerdotstar.com/community/node/512